# Check for spaces at the begining of a text (MYSQL query)

Tags: mysql, where-clause, wildcard, whitespace

my problem is this: I'm trying to find rows in a table (table_x) wherein a specific column (let's say col_1) the text has been inserted inappropriately (with one or more white spaces at the beginning). I can use the wildcard `" %"` to find a whitespace but, and that's the thing, it is case sensitive with the number of spaces (for instance, searching for `"    %"` gives a different result than search just for `" %")`. As I want to make sure I caught all the rows where the problem appears (with any number of whitespace at the start of the text), how can I do this?

Comment: I don't see the problem. You want to find rows with any number of whitespaces at the beginning. Why do you need to distinguish 1 space from 3 spaces?

Comment: If this is a one-off query, why not use a compare? `SELECT whatever FROM wherever WHERE column <> TRIM(column);`. This is a terrible query but, if it’s for the purpose of correcting data, it’ll get the job done.

Comment: If you search for 1 space, it will include all the rows with more than 1 space.